# Is there a .NET function to output a string based on a condition?

Tags: c#, .net

During webdevelopment there are a lot of scenario's where I want to output a string (e.g. a CSS-class) based on a condition.
Popular ones are: active, even, ...

After always repeating the same functions with a specific condition I'm now at a point I wrote a reusable one and want to add it to my helpers. Like this:

```
public static string StringOnCondition (condition, returnString) {
    return (condition) ? returnString : "";
}
```

This way I can use it in this scenario:

```
    <li class="classRoom">
        <a href="/messages/" class="classRoomName @Helpers.StringOnCondition(Model.Url == "/messages/", "active")">Inbox</a> 
    </li>
```

But actually, I can't believe there isn't a function like that allready in the .NET-framework.
So which one am I missing?

Comment: What are you using for web development? MVC with Razor? Webforms? Something else?

Comment: You mean like the [`switch` statement?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why do you need a function for? The `?` operator already does what you need. The point of using a function would be to have implementation in one place and use it wherever needed, so if you change behavior within that function, everything is 'updated'. Here, I don't see the point of creating function for operator. You can just use `@(Model.Url == "/messages/" ? "active" : string.Empty)`. It's shorter and it does what's needed. Or I'm missing the point?

Comment: Actually, you're right. It's totally unnecessary to have a function for that thanks to the ? operator. You can post this as an answer, this comment reflected my consideration to want a function for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need a function for? The `?` operator already does what you need. The point of using a function would be to have implementation in one place and use it wherever needed, so if you change behavior within that function, everything is 'updated'. Here, I don't see the point of creating function for operator. You can just use `@(Model.Url == "/messages/" ? "active" : string.Empty)`. It's shorter and it does what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I take the approach of moving the logic of which string to use into the view-model class. For example:

```
public class EmployeeRowViewModel
{
  public string CssClass {get;set;}
  public Employee Row {get;set;}
}
```

When building up the `RowViewModel`s, I assign the correct classes to each row, then when the model is used in the view, the correct CSS class string is used.

Usually when I see too much logic happening in a view I consider it a "bad smell" and try to factor out the logic into the view-model.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the new scenario posted by the original poster, I still believe the logic can be moved out of the view. For example you could add a calculated property to the view:

```
public class EmployeeRowViewModel
{
  public string CssClass {get;set;}
  public string Url {get;set;}
  public string CssActive
  {
    get { return (Url == "/messages/") ? "active" : null; }
  }
  public Employee Row {get;set;}
}
```

Then update your view to:

```
<li class="classRoom">
  <a href="/messages/" class="classRoomName @Model.CssActive">Inbox</a> 
</li>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any logic happening in the View, except maybe Javascript/jQuery UI manipulation stuff.

Comment: Thx for the useful comment. In the scenario you describe this is a very good hint => +1
Thought i'm looking for an other answer. I updated my question with a scenario I use all the time.

Comment: @Gigi2m02 I've updated my answer to account for your new scenario

Comment: It do is a very good practise what you're illustrating. Thx for your effort. It's something i'll definitely keep in mind in the (near) future. Though, the comment Kosta placed is the actual answer on my question.

Comment: @Gigi2m02 No problem, I'm glad you found what you're looking for

Comment: This is a good approach in general, since with this you can have more complex condition in a property.